# Managing keyword colors with listings

Tags: listings

I am working in a document that presents `R` code with the `listings` package, and I am having trouble with the font color with some characters and words that apparently are taken as first keywords.

In this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=R,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  keywordstyle=[2]{\color{red}},
  commentstyle=\color{gray},
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!25},
  morekeywords=[2]{arg,pos},
  moredelim=[is][\color{violet}]{''}{''}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
# define one / two / three characteristics
install(''"tree/site"'', arg = 1, pos = "t")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

that produces:
[image: listings output]

Here the slashes are printed in blue both in the comments and inside the quotes, and they do not respect the colors defined in `lstset`.

Besides `pos` that has explicitly defined as a `keywordstyle` `[2]` in red appears in blue.

I appreciate your help or suggestions.

Comment: I just have tried your example with package `minted` instead of `listings`.   It did mark the comment in one color.  Personally I think, the spacing between the glyphens is prettier, than with listings.

Comment: Thanks @Jan for the comment, and I'll check out the `minted` package. However, `listings` has ways to have prettier spacing like e.g. `basicstyle=\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont` in the `lstset` definition.

Comment: A common setting would be `basicstyle = \ttfamily, columns = fullflexible` for monospaced font

Comment: Yes, but I have already defined the `basicstyle` with `zi4` as in my above comment to Jan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pos` already is defined as keyword. You can remove before defining it new:

```
deletekeywords = {pos}
```

`/` also is defined as keyword but with `otherkeywords`. Unfortunately there is no `deleteotherkeywords` but you can set the list anew leaving `/` out:

```
otherkeywords = {!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,_}
```

The original definition of `R` where I found the above can be found in the file `lstlang3.sty`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=R,
  deletekeywords={pos},
  otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,_},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  keywordstyle=[2]{\color{red}},
  commentstyle=\color{gray},
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!25},
  morekeywords=[2]{arg,pos},
  moredelim=[is][\color{violet}]{''}{''}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
# define one / two / three characteristics
install(''"tree/site"'', arg = 1, pos = "t")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm and thanks a lot. 
I just was wondering why some `otherkeywords` work with `literate` within `lstset`like `literate= {<-}{{\ttfamily <-\;}}1` but for example `literate= {_}{{\ttfamily _}}1` gives a error. But the reference you gave is very helpful.