# How to display $ in listings Latex

Tags: listings

I need to write three different programming languages: C#, R and TensorFlow.
TensorFlow has the keyword `tf$` and i would like to have it as keyword in my latex file, but i have got an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\lstset{%
literate=
        {$}{{\${$}}}1
}

\lstdefinestyle{Common}
{
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily\null,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    tabsize=5,
    columns=flexible,
    showstringspaces=false,
    captionpos=b,% or t for top (default)
    abovecaptionskip=0.5\smallskipamount,   % there is also belowcaptionskip
}
\lstdefinestyle{Mathematica}
{
    style=Common,
    language={Mathematica},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
        Animate,
        AnimationRunning,
    },
    keywordstyle =\color{blue},
}
\lstdefinestyle{CSharp}
{
    style=Common,
    language={[Sharp]C},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
       %
    },
    keywordstyle =\color{blue},
}
\lstdefinestyle{R}
{
    style=Common,
    language={R},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
       %
    },
    keywordstyle =\color{blue},
}
\lstdefinestyle{TensorFlow}
{
    alsoletter = {$},
    style=Common,
    language={[Sharp]C},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
        tf$
    },
    keywordstyle =\color{blue},
}

\lstnewenvironment{Mathematica}
{\lstset{style=Mathematica}}
{}
\lstnewenvironment{CSharp}
{\lstset{style=CSharp}}
{}
\lstnewenvironment{R}
{\lstset{style=R}}
{}
\lstnewenvironment{TensorFlow}
{\lstset{style=TensorFlow}}
{}

\title{...}
\author{...}
\date{August 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{R}
fib <- function(n) {
  if (n < 2)
    n
  else
    fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
}
fib(10) # => 55
\end{R}

\begin{TensorFlow}
 sess$run(TF_up81a)
 tf$logical_not()
\end{TensorFlow}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using \ in the front of $ symbol.

Comment: I would like the symbol $ to be colored in blue like any other keywork

Comment: see this Q: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352506/managing-keyword-colors-with-listings

Answer (score 0):

Using   `mathescape = true,` but the keyword is not reconize.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\lstset{%
literate=
        {$}{{\${$}}}1
}

\lstdefinestyle{Common}
{
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily\null,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    tabsize=5,
    columns=flexible,
    showstringspaces=false,
    captionpos=b,% or t for top (default)
    abovecaptionskip=0.5\smallskipamount,   % there is also belowcaptionskip
}
\lstdefinestyle{Mathematica}
{
    style=Common,
    language={Mathematica},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
        Animate,
        AnimationRunning,
    },
    keywordstyle =\color{blue},
}
\lstdefinestyle{CSharp}
{
    style=Common,
    language={[Sharp]C},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
       %
    },
    keywordstyle =\color{blue},
}
\lstdefinestyle{R}
{
    style=Common,
    language={R},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
       %
    },
    keywordstyle =\color{blue},
}
\lstdefinestyle{TensorFlow}
{
  % alsoletter = {$},
%  escapechar= {$},
  mathescape = true,
    style=Common,
    language={[Sharp]C},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
        tf$\mathdollar$%
    },
    keywordstyle =\color{blue},
}

\lstnewenvironment{Mathematica}
{\lstset{style=Mathematica}}
{}
\lstnewenvironment{CSharp}
{\lstset{style=CSharp}}
{}
\lstnewenvironment{R}
{\lstset{style=R}}
{}
\lstnewenvironment{TensorFlow}
{\lstset{style=TensorFlow}}
{}

\title{...}
\author{...}
\date{August 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{R}
  fib <- function(n) {
    if (n < 2)
    n
    else
    fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
  }
fib(10) # => 55
\end{R}

\begin{TensorFlow}
 sess$\mathdollar$run(TF_up81a)
 $\color{blue}\rm{tf}\mathdollar$logical_not()
\end{TensorFlow}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If it is possible, I would like to copy and paste my code without changing it (`$` with `$\mathdollar$`)

Comment: @vrige, Yes I understand, but I don't know how to do